# Best method to create complex custom interface for IOS

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, user-interface, core-animation, core-graphics

I'd like to understand which is the best solution to draw custom interface for IOS application.
I know that it's not easy to answer this question directly with code, but i think that it would be great get generic answers... only to understand in which direction i have to go!

I use as example this Ipad RSS reader : 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKfZGF5kMYw

1) how to create for example the "Slide Page" effect shown in this video at 00:38

2) at 01:00 user move only a single element of the View (maybe a table Cell ?) how would you implement this effect ?

3) at 01:53 user pinch a preview item and the single element explodes in multiple items. In your opinion, is that effect created only with Core Graphics ? how would you implement it ?

Thank you for your answers! 
I hope this question will be useful for other people too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is done by using GestureRecognizer and CoreAnimation; these [WWDC 2010 Session Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/archive/) will be helpful:

- Session 120 - Simplifying Touch Event Handling with Gesture Recognizers
- Session 121 - Advanced Gesture Recognition
- Session 424 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 1
- Session 425 - Core Animation in Practice, Part 2

Comment: How do I see these? I click on the links in FF and get a popup to select iTunes, but they don't load. I can't find them on the Apple site.

Comment: Solution: I found the session videos on the Apple site using Safari (they do not have a download link in FireFox).